# 基底クラスのポインタ変数のインスタンスが何の型にダウンキャストしているかを知る方法が知りたい

Tags: c++

#### 質問内容

タイトル通りなのですが`基底クラスのポインタ変数のインスタンスが何の型にダウンキャストしているかを知る方法が知りたい`方法が知りたいです。`Component`を継承している各クラスで基底クラスに何に継承しているかの情報を残したいのですがそれをするにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

#### 考えたこと

以下のように実装すこと自体は出来ているのですが、`現状の実装｀部のように列挙型を使っていると、コンポーネントが増えた時(`Component`を継承するクラスが増えたときに)`　if文`で分岐する箇所をちょくちょく増やさにといけないのでので面倒です。

#### 現状での問題点

１，コンポーネントが増えた時(`Component`を継承するクラスが増えたときに)　`if文`で分岐する箇所を増えるとゲームループがシンプルじゃなくなるので複雑化します。

２，もっとシンプルなコンストラクタを作成したい。

#### 提示画像のついて

これは継承関係の図です。`Component`クラスは継承されるそれぞれのコンポーネントの基底クラスです。
また`GameObject`は`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>>`変数を持っていてメインループでそれを更新、描画します。

#### 試したこと

`Component`クラス型の`//`コメント部のように
1,`//実装１`,`//実装１` は`std::type_info`型を用いてどの型の情報を保存しようとしましたがコピーコンストラクタが実装されていないため実装不可です。

2,`//実装3`,`Component`クラスを自体をテンプレート型にするという方法で`std::type_info`型に代入することは出来たのですが、その場合`Component`型の変数を作成する際にどの型に継承するかわからないのに型を決めることになってしまうので実装不可です。

#### 現状の実装

`class Component`部の`//`コメント部`//現状`のように列挙型で基底クラス(`Component`)が何の型に継承しているかの情報を持たせています。

#### 実現したいこと

Componentクラスを継承した`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>>`でゲームループで一つづつアップデートやレンダリングする際にif文で分岐したい。

#### 知りたこと

`現状の実装`じゃない方法で基底クラスにどの型に継承しているかの情報をどうやって持たせればいいのか知りたい。
該当コード　`///////`部で囲ってる`if()`文

#### ソースコード

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <memory>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <locale.h>

class GameObject;
//template<class T> //実装3
class Component
{
public:
//    Component(Component* c) : info(typeid(*c))    //実装１ Error

/*
    Component(Component* c)・・実装２ Error
    {
        info = typeid(*c);
    }
*/
    //　何に継承しているかを識別するenum
    enum Type
    {
        SpriteRender,
        Transform,
    };

    //実装４ (現状)
    Component(GameObject *g,Type t) : type(t),gameObject(g)
    {

    }

    const Type type;
    const GameObject *gameObject;
    //const std::type_info &info = typeid(T)    //実装3

    virtual void f(){ }

};

class Component;
class GameObject
{

protected:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>> components; //コンポーネント変数

public:
    GameObject()
    {

    }

    /*
        コンポーネント取得

        基底(Component)クラスにアップキャストされたコンポーネントからダウンキャストしたコンポーネント(SpriteRender,Transform　等)を取得
    */
    template<class T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> GetComponent()
    {
        for(std::shared_ptr<Component> c : components)
        {
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if(true)
            {
                return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(c);
            }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }

        return nullptr; // コンポーネントがない場合の時
    }


    /*
        コンポーネント設定

        基底クラスにアップキャストして格納
    */
    template<class T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> AddComponent()
    {
        if(GetComponent<T>() != nullptr)
        {
            components.push_back(std::make_shared<T>());

            return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(components.back());
        }

        return nullptr; // コンポーネントがすでにある場合
    }

};

class SpriteRender : public Component
{
public:
    SpriteRender(GameObject *g) : Component(g,Component::Type::SpriteRender)
    {

    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout<<"class SpriteRender member " <<std::endl;
    }
    
};

class Transform : public Component
{
public:
    Transform(GameObject *g) : Component(g,Component::Type::Transform)
    {

    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout<<"class Transform member " <<std::endl;
    }
    
};

int main()
{       


    return 0;
}
```

#### 継承関係図

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 質問趣旨は「`shared_ptr<GameObject>`が指す先の派生先クラス型を知りたい」と解釈しましたが、その情報が得られたとして具体的に何をしたいのでしょうか？直接要件を満たすには`dynamic_pointer_cast`利用がベターに聞こえます。

Comment: 派生クラスの型を知って何をしたいのでしょうか？そもそも派生クラスの型を知らなければならない（基底クラスのまま処理できない）設計が間違っている可能性が高いです。

Comment: yohjp氏　いえ基底クラスにアップキャストされたComponentクラスのインスタンスの型が何か知りたいのです

Comment: alpha氏なるほど。ではこの場合どうするのが設計として正しいのでしょうか？UnityEngineのスクリプトリファレンスの継承関係を参考に作成しているのですが。ちなみにゲーム用の openglフレームワークです。コンポーネント指向で行いたいです

Comment: クラスで何をカプセル化（隠蔽）したいか／するのが良いかによって、クラス階層やその使用方法は変わってくるので、何が正しい設計なのかは現状の質問文からは分かりません。一般的には、（C++の場合は）抽象クラスを用いて（具象クラスを知らずに）使用できるようにクラス階層を設計するのが良いとされています。「UnityEngineのスクリプトリファレンスの継承関係」の具体例や仕様等が説明されれば、何か回答できることがあるかもしれません。

Comment: UnityEngineのスクリプトリファレンスを見ていたのですがComponentはすべてのコンポーネントの基底クラスなのでコンポーネントはそれを継承するように設計したいのですが。ゲームループされるときにすべてのコンポーネントをアップデートする時、描画されるものとアップデートされるものと何もしないものとあるときにどのコンポーネントが何をするのか知る必要があるので質問文のようなことを考えたました。

Comment: 型を知った後、何をするのですか？ その型が持つメンバー関数を呼び出すのでは？ そうであれば、最初にyohjpさんがコメントしたように、キャストして成功したら、そのメンバー関数を呼び出すだけではありませんか？ 「型を知る」は手段の１つでしかないはずが、目的化しているように見受けられます。あるいはXY問題。

Comment: そうですか。if文による分岐等いろいろシンプルじゃないと思ったので質問したのですが

Comment: まず仮想関数（抽象クラス）を勉強するべきです。基底クラスに共通のインターフェイス（仮想関数）を定義して、派生クラスで具体的処理を定義（オーバーライド）すれば、if文で派生クラス毎の処理を分けるなんてことは、ほとんど不要です。

Comment: なるほど。そのときに各派生クラスになったときに基底クラスの仮想関数で利用しない関数が出てくると思いますがそれは設計としどうなのでしょうか？

Comment: 継承によってポリモーフィズムを実現しているのであれば、基底クラスの関数を利用しない(あるいは実行されても何もしないようにオーバーライドする)というのは、別に特殊なことはなく、あたりまえの選択肢の一つだと思いますが、何か問題があるのでしょうか。
ただ、あまりにも一部の派生クラスでのみ使用する特殊な処理が増えていくようだったら、クラス設計を見直す必要が出てくるとは思いますが。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

結局何をやりたいのか今一分かりませんし、[UnityEngineの仕様](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html)を良く分かっていないので本当にこんな使い方を意図しているのか分かりませんが、列挙子を使わずに派生クラスの型に応じて関数を呼び分けることは技術的には可能です。
ただし、ダウンキャストを多用するので処理効率は悪いですし、きっとUnityEngineはこんな使い方を意図していないだろうと思います。

コード例：

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


class Component
{
public:
    virtual ~Component() = default;

    std::string TypeName() const
    {
        return typeid(*this).name();
    }
};

class Renderer : public Component
{
public:
    virtual void Render() = 0;
};

class SpriteRenderer : public Renderer
{
public:
    virtual void Render() override
    {
        std::cout << TypeName() << " - func " << __func__ << "\n";
    }
};

class Transform : public Component
{
public:
    void TransformDirection()
    {
        std::cout << TypeName() << " - func " << __func__ << "\n";
    }
};

class GameObject
{
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>> m_components;

public:
    template<class T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> AddComponent()
    {
        auto component = std::make_shared<T>();
        m_components.push_back(component);
        return component;
    }

    template<class T>
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> GetComponents() const
    {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> components;
        for (auto &component : m_components)
        {
            if (auto componentT = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(component))
            {
                components.push_back(componentT);
            }
        }
        return components;
    }
};

int main()
{
    GameObject  gameObject;

    gameObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    gameObject.AddComponent<Transform>();
    gameObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    gameObject.AddComponent<Transform>();

    auto spriteRenderers = gameObject.GetComponents<SpriteRenderer>();
    for (auto &spriteRenderer : spriteRenderers)
    {
        spriteRenderer->Render();
    }

    // Rendererでもヒットする
    auto renderers = gameObject.GetComponents<Renderer>();
    for (auto &renderer : renderers)
    {
        renderer->Render();
    }

    auto transforms = gameObject.GetComponents<Transform>();
    for (auto &transform : transforms)
    {
        transform->TransformDirection();
    }
}
```

Visual Studio 2022での実行結果：

```
class SpriteRenderer - func Render
class SpriteRenderer - func Render
class SpriteRenderer - func Render
class SpriteRenderer - func Render
class Transform - func TransformDirection
class Transform - func TransformDirection
```

Answer (score 1):

【`type_info` を用いてやりたかったけども→それをうまくやれなかったから現状enumになっている】という件についてですが，
`type_info` を用いる判定をする手段としては，`Component` クラスに

`virtual bool Is( const type_info &ti ) const { return ti==typeid(Component);   }`

みたいなメソッドを設ければどうでしょうか？
そしたら，例えば派生型の `Transform` ではこんな感じでしょうか：

`virtual bool Is( const type_info &ti ) const override {    return Component::Is(ti) || (ti==typeid(Transform));    }`

これを用いると型の判定のところは

`if( c->Is( typeid(T) ) )`

みたいな感じの判定になる…と．

※しかしそもそもこういう判定をやってくれるのが `dynamic_cast` 等なわけで，それを自前でやる意味があるのか？と言われると「うーん」という感じですが…
（例えば `dynamic_cast` よりも「自前判定+`static_cast`」の方が早いだとかいうような，何かしらの意義があるのでもなければ無意味な気がする）

Comment: 回答末尾の `static_cast` がどうの，という話については……alpha氏の回答にあるリンク「UnityEngineの仕様」から辿ってみると，GetComponent() の戻り値は Component 型であって派生型ではない様子だったので，それにならって本件でも `shared_ptr<Component>` を戻り値型とするなら，それを受け取った側では `static_cast` でいけるかな，とかそんな感じ．